# Deployment of Virtual Service using @kubernetes/client-node nodejs api

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, istio

I am using `@kubernetes/client-node nodejs` API for deployment of Docker image.I could find apis for deployment of docker image and for creation of service.But there is no specific api for virtual service creation. It is working through command line.

What is the api in `@kubernetes/client-node` for creation of virtual service?

Comment: what command you ran to do it from command line? Are you talking about Istio virtual service?

Comment: I ran kubectl apply -f VirtualService.yaml from command line. Yes I am talking about Istio virtual service through nodejs API

Answer (score 0):

Virtual service is a custom resource.Unfortunately client libraries will not have APIs for custom resources. Found this [example](https://dwmkerr.com/manipulating-istio-and-other-custom-kubernetes-resources-in-golang/) of patching a istio virtual service using golang client . You need to try to create instead of patch. I am not 100 percent sure if this works or not.

Edit: You can install kubectl in the docker image of your pod and then execute it via code. For example in python `subprocess.check_output(['kubectl', 'apply', '-f', 'virtual-service.yaml'])`

Comment: I have virtual service yaml file. Can you please elaborate on  **using the kubernetes library apply the yaml to the kubernetes cluster**?

Comment: Yaml File:                                                                                                                 
apiVersion: "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
kind: VirtualService
metadata: 
 name: "svc-model-service-proj"
spec: 
 hosts: 
  - 
   "*"
 gateways: 
  - 
   "testistio-gateway"
 http: 
  - 
   match: 
    - 
   uri: 
      prefix: "/"
   route: 
    - 
   destination: 
      host: "svc-model-service-proj"

Comment: Can you explain why are you trying to apply the yamls using client library? This is not a common pattern.